# Select twice from one query MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following select statement:

```
$wishes = mysql_query("select count(*) as how_many_total, PRprodinfo_id, main_category from user_lists where user_id = '$user_cookie' order by main_category;",$db);
```

Now, halfway down my page i need to extract the how_many_total value, then, if that is above 0 i need to run a fetch array on this query to print the results out

Do i need to use two queries to do this? e.g. one to count then if > 0 another select? when I try to fetch array twice or even combo of fetch row then fetch array i get errors

many thanks

darren

Comment: why not simply use `while( $wishes->fetch() ){ printing the results }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can let the complete count(*) out of your query and just use

```
if (mysql_num_rows($wishes) > 0)
```

to get the number of results and then do whatever you want like fetching the rows